# How can i change the input or outputDoc name after the mapping was done?

Tags: webmethods, eai

In webMethods designer I have mapped some of the fields the ***Input doc***(StudentInfo) to ***Output doc***(StudentPersonalInfo).

Now the requirement is the outputDoc Name must be changed from 
*StudentPersonalInfo-->StudentPersonalInfo2*.

How can I directly change the output doc name that will reflect in the respecive services by new name.

I tried to change the the doc name by **`IntegrationServer\packages\<packageName>\ns\<foldername>\flow`** but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by "Raghava Rudrakanth P V", it's not recommended to manually modify the flow.xml.

However, the recommended way, as described by "Raghava" is much more tedious.

If you know what you are doing, you can open the flow.xml file in a text editor and simply replace occurrences of `StudentPersonalInfo` to `StudentPersonalInfo2`.

Note: Be wary about document references if you also have fully qualified document names containing `StudentPersonalInfo`.

Make sure that you **reloaded the package** after you made the change so that the flow.xml file gets reloaded into memory by the webMethods engine.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @ Tchi Yuan .what i did first time was the same except the reloading the package. now i just added the step to reload the package in it.and now it's working fine ;) .. Thank you Guys for your help.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Changing the flow.xml is not recommended. In Designer

- Go to the pipeline tab of the particular flow step
- create a new document "StudentPersonalInfo2"
- select all fields under in "StudentPersonalInfo" and move them out of this document (by clicking shift left arrow mark)
- Move them into the new document. (use shift arrow keys)

Comment: In pipeline tab of the respective map step when i select all the fields of "StudentPersonalInfo" and try to move them out by clicking left arrow mark it doesn't shift .and if i do change in Input tab then i have to remap all the fields.(that i don't expect)

Comment: (In your case the arrows shouldn't be enabled at all, confirm this). Keep a dummy map step before the actual mapping and drop the "StudentPersonalnfo". then in the after map step you can shift the fields from "StudentPersonalInfo" to "StudentPersonalInfo2".